# Can the user agent be used to tie a cookie to hardware?

Tags: cookies, http-headers, ip-address, user-agent, mac-address

I help maintain a site that is sold to about 100 clients. We take security pretty seriously and we have a multiple step login process. One part of the process can be skipped if you have already logged in before and choose to get a cookie. When you login again and still have that cookie, that step is skipped. Of course, the value in the cookie is random and different for every user.

My boss wants to make it impossible to copy the cookie to another computer. Of course, I've explained that is not possible, but he still insists it is by requiring the user agent to remain the same.

> "We can then document that we have a “hardened” cookie that is specific to the user’s hardware and software."

Of course, I've explained that spoofing the user agent would be many many times more easy to do than spoofing the cookie value, and compared it to putting a band-aid on a padlock. Not to mention any opportunity you have at copying the cookie would allow you to copy the user agent as well. He doesn't care.

It doesn't bother me to require the same user agent but I have some integrity and a problem working on something being sold with such a lie about its security.

I'm a professional not a grunt. I wouldn't design a bridge that supports one weight when I know will be advertised as supporting a higher weight.

Am I being reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest an [alternative](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/no-sessions.html), since cookies are [not intended](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html) to provide security:

*

> An active network attacker can overwrite Secure cookies from an insecure channel, disrupting their integrity

- 

> Transport-layer encryption, such as that employed in HTTPS, is insufficient to prevent a network attacker from obtaining or altering a victim's cookies because the cookie protocol itself has various vulnerabilities.

- 

> A server that uses cookies to authenticate users can suffer security vulnerabilities because some user agents let remote parties issue HTTP requests from the user agent (e.g., via HTTP redirects or HTML forms).  When issuing those requests, user agents attach cookies even if the remote party does not know the contents of the cookies, potentially letting the remote party exercise authority at an unwary server.

- 

> Cookies do not provide integrity guarantees for sibling domains (and their subdomains).  For example, consider foo.example.com and bar.example.com.  The foo.example.com server can set a cookie with a Domain attribute of "example.com" (possibly overwriting an existing   "example.com" cookie set by bar.example.com), and the user agent will include that cookie in HTTP requests to bar.example.com.  In the worst case, bar.example.com will be unable to distinguish this cookie from a cookie it set itself.  The foo.example.com server might be
> able to leverage this ability to mount an attack against bar.example.com.

- 

> Cookies rely upon the Domain Name System (DNS) for security.  If the DNS is partially or fully compromised, the cookie protocol might fail to provide the security properties required by applications.

**References**

- [Sharing a Session across multiple domains](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0906sharingasessionacrossmultipledom01.html)
- [RFC 7258: Pervasive Monitoring is an Attack](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7258)

Answer (score 1):

A cookie that has a signature involving a server side "secret" and using the user agent as part of the salt will be more difficult to spoof, than a cookie that does not have the user agent as part of the salt. That is indisputable. First of all, it takes time to figure out how the salt is created - and a lot of "attackers" will be discouraged immediately.

*Yes, but it is not more secure...*

Your boss has a goal; to be able to tell his customers that the cookie is "hardened". You shouldn't assume that your boss does not understand the implications.

The fact is; it won't affect your applications security at all in either direction. It will however result in the cookie being *slightly* more difficult to move from one machine to another, and it will make the cookie stop working if the client updates his browser or flash version or changes his user agent in other ways.

Conclusion:

If everything else is equal, I consider the user agent salt in cookies as better than no user agent salt, by a tiny amount. I guess you could implement the thing faster than the time you spent asking this question.